# Https web service issue in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ssl

When I try to add https web service to .net framework project. It is throwing below error. I tried `svcutil` to generate wsdl. Still getting same error. How to fix this?

```
    The document at the url https://dev.company.com/webservices/spws/SharePoint/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'https://dev.company.com/webservices/spws/SharePoint/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx?disco'.'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
- Report from 'https://dev.company.com/webservices/spws/SharePointAMSIntegration/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://dev.company.com/webservices/spws/SharePoint/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://dev.company.com/webservices/spws/SharePoint/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

**Update: This is proxy url (https). Actual .asmx file sits on http server.**

Comment: what are the actual steps you are taking to consume the webservice in your project..?

Comment: Just add Service Reference to project and entered url and click go. got this error.

Comment: The server is failing. Look at the event log on the server.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the asmx file? Also, if you put that URL isn't a browser, what do you see? You should see the file contents. If not, you have a problem.

Comment: what name are you giving for the webservice for example I create one with a url pointing to http://myHost-Wxys-beta.mysite.com/wsCommonFunctions/clsSMTP.asmx? in the solution explorer it just shows a reference to my clsSmtp class. perhaps you are not consuming it properly.. also what version of VS are you using.. the steps are different in 2008 vs 2010

Comment: What do you mean with `This is proxy url (https). Actual .asmx file sits on http server` ? Does your proxy support `https`?

Comment: We deployed this web service on http: //dev.company.com:9111/SharePoint/SharePointCustomerManagement.asmx. In our main proxy server. we created a proxy url entry that point to original web service. On browser, we are able generate wsdl. But not with project.

Comment: **1)** I see mixed `http`s and `https`s **2)** try to save your generated wsdl on browser and give that file to svcutil

Comment: How? I saved .wsdl file in c drive. How to give this to svcutil?

Comment: something like `svcutil c:\....` or `svcutil file://c:.....`